# Redirect from one page to another in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to move from one-page App.js to addWork.js. I added a button to redirect the user to addWork.js in App.js but the strange thing is that the page is redirecting to the same page(App.js interface) but the URL change to be addWork.

I used the following code in render():

```
<Router>
    <Route>
    <button type="button" id="Add-new-work" > <Link to='/addWork'>Add new work</Link></button>
    </Route>
   </Router>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically navigate using React router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import and add the path in the index.js file. like follows:

```
    <Route>
      <Route component={AddWork} path='addWork' />   
    </Route>
```

You are not specifying the path, that's why it is redirecting to the same page

Comment: I added <Route>
      <Route component={AddWork} path='addWork' />   
    </Route> to index.js and an error shows up saying that 'AddWork' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: The code of index.js is as follow: ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
   
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  
  document.getElementById('root')
);

<Route>
      <Route  path='addWork' />   
    </Route>.  I want to make sure that I am adding it in a right way.

Comment: Did you import it first in index.js page like this: import AddWork from '.your component path'??

Comment: yes i did like this (import addWork from'./addWork';) they are on the same folder. I am using classes.

Comment: please check the spelling of the addWork component when exported. is it addWork or AddWork?

Comment: Class name is addWork. Do you know How can I run addWork directly without going through App.js?

Comment: can you share codesandbox version of your code?

Comment: I can't share code using comments because it is limited in characters. I am using "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.7.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "solc": "^0.8.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.6",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0",
    "web3": "^1.3.4"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to specifying your `Route` components, don't forget to add `exact` to the `/` Route. If you didn't do that and your Home Route is on top of the others you will keep navigating to the Home page.

your code should be similar to this:

```
    <Router>
        <Route exact path="/">
            <button type="button" id="Add-new-work">
                <Link to='/addWork'>
                   Add new work
                </Link>
            </button>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/addWork">
            you are in the addWork Route!
        </Route>
   </Router>
```

Comment: Thank you @fayez I tried to change the code to the code you shared with me but unfortunately, it is not redirecting to the addWork page.

Comment: The link changes to be /addWork and the button that redirects to addWork disappeared but the page content is the same as the home content.